# Debugging .NET dynamic methods

Tags: c#, .net, linq, debugging, dynamic-method

We are using LINQ very widely in our system. Particularly LINQ-to-objects. So in some places we end up having a LINQ query in memory build up from some huge expressions. The problem comes when there's some bug in the expressions. So we get NullReferenceException and the stack trace leads us nowhere (to [Lightweight Function]). The exception was thrown inside the dynamic method generated by LINQ.

Is there any easy way to debug such dynamic methods? Or do I have to sacrifice myself to learning WinDBG? :-)

Comment: Linq to objects usually refers to the methods of System.Linq.Enumerable .  These do not involve dynamic methods (but can involve anonymous methods).  Are you really using dynamic methods?

Comment: @David - I asked the same; Orlangur is using AsQueryable to use the same code with multiple sources - so dynamic methods are expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are building your own expressions and compiling them, or using AsQueryable, then yes; the LINQ-generated methods will be a royal pain to debug.

You can save some pain by using small fragements of *actual* methods - at least something useful will show in the stack trace...

Another consideration is: rather than having one huge expression, if you can daisy-chain things a bit more you might have more idea (from the stack trace) where it is failing. The downside is performance - a Where(foo).Where(bar) is two delegate invokes, where-as Where(foo && bar) can be one.

One option might be to swap in a debug version of the extension methods; unfortunately it is a little inconvenient because `IQueryable<T>` and `Queryable` are in the same namespace... this works, though...

Output first:

```
>Where: x => ((x % 2) = 0)
<Where: x => ((x % 2) = 0)
>Count
'WindowsFormsApplication2.vshost.exe' (Managed): Loaded 'Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly'
<Count
```

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace Demo
{
    using DebugLinq;
    static class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var data = System.Linq.Queryable.AsQueryable(new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });
            data.Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Count(); 
        }
    }
}
namespace DebugLinq
{
    public static class DebugQueryable
    {
        public static int Count<T>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<T> source)
        {
            return Wrap(() => System.Linq.Queryable.Count(source), "Count");
        }

        public static System.Linq.IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this System.Linq.IQueryable<T> source, Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate)
        {
            return Wrap(() => System.Linq.Queryable.Where(source, predicate), "Where: " + predicate);
        }
        static TResult Wrap<TResult>(Func<TResult> func, string caption)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(">" + caption);
            try
            {
                TResult result = func();
                Debug.WriteLine("<" + caption);
                return result;
            }
            catch
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("!" + caption);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately actual methods are not an option in our case since the code that builds the expressions is used with other LINQ providers too  so it has to work with IQueryable

Comment: Well, I guess I can create my own LINQ-to-objects provider specifically for debugging that will evaluate all the expressions step-by-step recursively and will replace queryable method calls with enumerable method calls. That should solve the problem. Not an easy task itself however.

Comment: Indeed. Sorry, I can't think of anything better, except to manually break your expressions down into small pieces when unit testing... not always easy.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using LINQ to Objects, I wouldn't expect to see dynamic methods being created. I'd expect them with LINQ to SQL etc. Could you give an example where you're seeing this?

I don't really have any good debugging tips when it comes to LINQ, but I'm pretty sure MS know about this as a pain point. Could I suggest you try the [VS2010 CTP](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=922B4655-93D0-4476-BDA4-94CF5F8D4814&displaylang=en) and see if that's better? More for the sake of improving VS than for solving your immediate problem, admittedly.

Comment: By LINQ to Objects I mean using in-memory collections via AsQueryable()

Comment: So why AsQueryable? *generally* IEnumerable<T> is simpler, and it means that simple lambdas can get used directly. You can still .Compile() your manually built lambdas to use them...

Comment: Jon, can you please update the link, I wanted to check out the link but it does not work anymore. Thnx

Comment: @cpoDesign: Well nearly four years later, we've nearly got a release for VS2012, and VS2010 has been live for a long time... effectively, this answer is no longer useful, and I'll delete it when I've given you a little while to check this comment.

Comment: No need to delete it, just have been curious to read what you have suggested. pav

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [debug visualizer](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2007/11/02/debugger-visualizers-for-methodinfo-dynamicmethod-and-methodbase.aspx) for dynamic methods originally developed by [Haibo Luo](http://blogs.msdn.com/haibo_luo/archive/2005/10/25/484861.aspx) and taken further by [Roy Osherove](http://weblogs.asp.net/rosherove/archive/2006/04/25/MethodsVisualizer.aspx)